# Vertically center an HTML header

Tags: html, css

I can not seem to get my header to have the titles centered in the middle of the header box. How it looks now, it has the news, contacts, and about links high up in the box and not centered.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li style="float:left"><a class="active" <a onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target);return false;" href="http://link/" target="link"> <img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo"    style="width:125px;height:75px;"></a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: red;
}

.active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link the the div site?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking about **vertical** centering, _not_ horizontal centering?

Comment: yes vertically centered

Comment: Can you post your code in jsfiddle? Or maybe a screenshot of how it appears? Btw, your html code doesn't seem good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on the `<li>`:

```
.li {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[how this works](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

**EDIT:** Cleaned up some unbalanced HTML issues and cleaned up the css:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px; /* adjust as necessary */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="active" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target);return false;" href="http://link/" target="link"> <img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:125px;height:75px;"></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not quite, instead of having them in a line, it stacks them on top of each oth

Answer (score 0):

here's a more modern approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/qq0t46pt/2/

flexbox is also well supported now, and easier to implement.

---

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li style="float:left"><a class="active"> <a onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target);return false;" href="http://link/" target="link"> <img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo"    style="width:125px;height:75px;"></a></a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;

    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 370px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: red;
}

.active {
    background-color: black;
}
```